# Inequalities regarding the geometric dimension of groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, geometric-group-theory

I'm studying some group cohomology, and I'm stuck on the following problem (namely, problem VIII.1.3 of Brown's *Cohomology of Groups*): let's define the *geometric dimension* of a group $G$ as
$$
\text{gd}G = \inf\{n \, | \, \dim_{CW}(X), \, X \text{ a classifying space for }G \},
$$
where we take as classifying spaces the $K(G,1)$'s that are also path-connected CW-complexes.

Similarly to the case of cohomological dimension (where the *cohomological dimension* of $G$ is defined as the infimum of the length of projective resolutions of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z} G$), I would like to show the following:

1. if $A \subset G$ is a group inclusion, then
   $$
   \text{gd} A \leq \text{gd} G;
   $$
2. If $1 \to G_1 \to G \to G_2 \to 1$ is a group extension, then
   $$
   \text{gd} G \leq \text{gd} G_1 + \text{gd} G_2;
   $$
3. If $G = G_1 \ast_A G_2$ where $A \subset G_1, G_2$, then
   $$
   \text{gd} G \leq \max \{\text{gd} G_1, \text{gd} G_2, 1 + \text{gd} A\}.
   $$

**My attempt:**

*For 1:* this is more or less clear. Any classifying space $X$ as above admits an universal cover $\tilde{X} \to X$; by the classification theorem of connected covers of $X$, we get another cover $p_A: Y \to X$ such that ${p_{A}}_\ast(\pi_1(Y)) = A \subset G = \pi_1(X)$, and the induced map $\tilde{X} \to Y$ is also a cover.

I claim that $Y$ is a classifying space: first of all, since ${p_A}_\ast$ is injective, $\pi_1(Y) \cong A$. Moreover, $\tilde{X}$ is a CW complex (by lifting the CW-structure from $X$) such that $\dim_{CW}(\tilde{X}) = \dim_{CW}(X)$, and $\pi_{\geq 2}(\tilde{X}) = \pi_{\geq 2}(X) = 0$; by the same reasoning $Y$ is a CW-complex, $\pi_{\geq 2}(\tilde{Y}) = \pi_{\geq 2}(Y) = 0$ and we have that $\dim(Y) \leq \dim(X)$.

*For 2:* here I'm stuck. I know I can get a fibre sequence $K(G_1,1) \to K(G,1) \to K(G_2,1)$, and then use the Serre spectral sequence to get, for any abelian group $M$,
$$
H^p(K(G_2,1);H^q(K(G_1,1);M)) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(K(G,1);M),
$$
and for $k> \text{gd}G_2 + \text{gd} G_1$, by taking $p+q =k$ and by the vanishing of the second page, I get that $H^{k}(K(G,1); M) \cong 0$. Is this enough to conclude? If yes, how?

*For 3:* also here I'm stuck, similarly as before. Briefly, the idea I have is: take $X_1$ and $X_2$ classifying spaces for $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively, minimizing the dimensions. Since $A \subset G_1, G_2$ and $\text{Hom}(A, G_i) \cong [K(A,1), K(G_i,1)]_\ast$, we can find maps from $X_A$, the $K(A,1)$ minimizing the dimension for $A$, fitting in a diagram of cellular maps:
$$
X_1 \leftarrow X_A \rightarrow X_2
$$

By taking the pushout and calling it $X$, by van Kampen and Mayer-Vietoris (applied on the universal cover), this should be a classifying space for $G$. I guess that at this point (at least intuitively) $\text{gd} G \leq \max\{\text{gd} G_1, \text{gd} G_2 \}$, but I can't get the dimension of $A$ coming into play here (maybe I should use some sort of Mayer-Vietoris technique here)? Also, does this make sense, even though it's really sketchy?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that $cd=gd$ except possibly in the case $cd=2$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I didn't know about this. I've checked into Brown's and the (so called) Eilenberg-Ganea theorem you mention is presented way after this exercise is asked (section 7 of the same chapter). Also, does this allow us to conclude? Because it's not clear to me.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Take for example the third point. The critical part now is to show, for a group having cd$G = 2$ and possibly gd$G = 3$, the above inqualities. I don't see why it should be straightforward to have now $\max \{\text{gd}G_i,1+\text{gd}A\}$ bigger or equal than $3$.

Comment: For 3: If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a cellular map, $\mathrm{dim}(Zf) = \mathrm{max}\{\mathrm{dim}(X)+1, \mathrm{dim}(Y)\}$, $X\to Zf$ is the inclusion of a subcomplex and $Zf\to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence. Here $Zf$ is the mapping cylinder. Apply this to your pushout. The 2nd one is trickier, I don't know a solution off the top of my head.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thanks! This makes total sense.